# How to integrate fortumo In-App purchase plugin to Corona Sdk game?

Tags: coronasdk, fortumo

I am trying to integrate the fortumo In-App purchase plugin to my game

I am currently following the documentation on there home page but i don't get it.

http://developers.fortumo.com/in-app-purchasing-for-corona/making-a-payment/
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/05/30/increasing-app-revenue-with-fortumo-mobile-payments/

here i have tryed to do it so but i don't think this is the right way.
I have placed the whole code on button click listener.

```
   local GUI = display.newGroup();
   local fortumo = require("plugin.fortumo")
   local request = fortumo.newPaymentRequest();

   request:setDisplayString("Super Powers #1");
   request:setService("463ab812a5d0483c06a976b3d8084ef8", "9c21d58f14c1328fc9772b6d507ca566");
   request:setProductName("ProductSKU-User123");
   request:setConsumable(false); 
   fortumo.makePayment(request, onPaymentComplete);

   function onPaymentComplete(response)
       print("complete=" .. response.billingStatus);
   end
   onPayme
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

See:  https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/fortumo/index.html
There is a link to sample code at the bottom.  Between that document, and the sample code you should be able to get going..